# How to make this refer to the constructor

Tags: javascript, click, this

I have the following code

```
function perso (image_mere, emplacement_x, emplacement_y, x, y, direction) {
         this.source = image_mere;
         this.sprite = createElement('div');

         // some other properties                       
         this.sprite.addEventListener('click', function() {
         dindong = this;
         (function(dindong) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            alert(dingdong.image_mere)
         })(dindong);
    }, true);
};
```

As you can see, the keyword this refers to the sprite, howerver i want to refer to the object so i can get the properties :/
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
}.bind(this), true);  //this is last line of your listener
```